# What is the best way to integrate Microsoft Teams operator in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow, microsoft-teams

Current I am using Apache Airflow for sending files through mails.
But I want to send files on teams.
MY Airflow version : 1.10.15

Something like trigger dags through teams and get response/data back.

Comment: Before you can do something the best way you need first to have some way. Do you have a working python code that send file through Microsoft Teams? If not start there. If you do have it then wrap it with Python function and invoke it with PythonOperator. Later, if needed you can create a custom operator from it.

Comment: Could you please refer this link and check if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/working-with-files-in-your-microsoft-teams-bot/